# R - merging 2 data frames by common key "Isin" but ignoring last two numbers

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, data.table

I want to merge two dataframes df1 and df2 by the common key "Isin" with the data.table package (exmpl. below). Everything seemed to work pretty well until I found out that  some companies like Volkswagen or BMW give out different kind of shares namely    "stock without par value" and " preferred shares". 
Tha fact that both DFs originate from different sources makes it complicated to handle these differences manually due to the large sample size of about 15,000.

```
dt1 <- data.table(df1, key = "Isin") 
dt2 <- data.table(df2, key = "Isin")
joined.dt1.dt.2 <- dt1[dt2]
```

I found out that that the Isins of these both kinds of shares only differ in the last two numbers e.g.:

Volkswagen:

DE0007664039

DE0007664005

BMW:

DE0005190037

DE0005190003

To merge both DFs, I could practically just delete the last two numbers of the Isin in both Dfs and the merging would work.
But I guess there has to be more elgant way to manage this issue without deleting the last two numbers of each Isin.

Does anybody know another, more elegant aproach like just "ignoring" the last two numbers?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have A01 joined to A02, which one of those values should show up in the result? There are some comments on the issue tracker about "fuzzy" joins which may help: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1431

Comment: @Frank, thank you for your response. Which value to show is actually not important in my case. Only important to keep one of both in one piece.